# Enable & disable cronjob remotely in suse linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, quoting

I am executing below command to remotely disable and enable cron job on linux server but command not disabling cron job on remote server.Although it's working when trying on same server.

```
ssh mysql@$pas_ser_name "crontab -l | sed "/^[^#].*$job_name/s/^/#/" | crontab -"
```

Could anyone help on same.I want to enable and disable linux job remotely with job name.

Comment: "Not working" is always an insufficient bug report.  Please be more specific on ② what you expected and ③ what you observed.  (You got the "① what you did" alright.)

Comment: mysql@qa:~>   crontab -l
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (/tmp/crontab.xKL9b0 installed on Wed Jan  3 08:07:27 2018)
# (Cronie version 4.2)
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (/tmp/crontab.EtnRqI installed on Wed Jan  3 06:49:06 2018)
# (Cronie version 4.2)
11 11 * * 0 ksh /mysql-backup/var/run/.server_info.ksh > /dev/null 2>&1
*/15 * * * * sh /mysql-work/bin/active_status_check.sh 2>/tmp/active_status.out

Comment: mysql@amdc-sqladmin-lx02:~/chandra> echo $pas_ser_name
qa-mysqldb-lx06.amdc.mckinsey.com

Comment: I propose you change your question (instead of adding relevant information in a comment) to retain a readable format.

Comment: One more thing while we are changing crontab in remote server it is adding crontab version again & again.

# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (- installed on Wed Jan  3 08:12:19 2018)
# (Cronie version 4.2)
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (/tmp/crontab.D0RSRi installed on Wed Jan  3 08:12:08 2018)
# (Cronie version 4.2)
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (/tmp/crontab.EtnRqI installed on Wed Jan  3 06:49:06 2018)
# (Cronie version 4.2)

Comment: @Alfe: Could you please let me know.What to remove from question.As I am seeing you are removing all answer from this post.

Comment: You see what??  I am not removing anything.  I suggest you should not *remove* anything from your question but *add* something to it, namely the information you tried to add in a comment here (where it gets completely garbled because in comments you cannot format properly).

Comment: There were two answers which were removed by their owners, probably because *they* had second thoughts about them.  Actually, one was pretty okay (but a bit short), and I even upvoted it (after first wrongly thinking it was bad).

Comment: @Alfe: I apologize for my comment of deleting answer.

Comment: Below command are working fine but issue is it is duplicating comment in cron.Is there any way of doing same without duplicating comment on cron.Please see attached image to get more insight of problem.

ssh mysql@$pas_ser_name "crontab -l |sed '/$job_name/s/^/#/' |crontab -" 


ssh mysql@$pas_ser_name "crontab -l |sed '/$job_name/s/^#//' |crontab -"

Comment: mysql@:~> crontab -l
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (- installed on Wed Jan  3 08:51:56 2018)
# (Cronie version 4.2)
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (- installed on Wed Jan  3 08:51:41 2018)
# (Cronie version 4.2)
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (/tmp/crontab.uPPcCr installed on Wed Jan  3 08:51:28 2018)
# (Cronie version 4.2)
11 11 * * 0 ksh /mysql-backup/var/run/.server_info.ksh > /dev/null 2>&1
*/15 * * * * sh /mysql-work/bin/active_status_check.sh 2>/tmp/active_status.out

Answer (score 0):

crontab -l | grep -v 'wget php -q http://www.example.com/event_reminder.php' | crontab -
crontab -l lists the current crontab jobs

grep -v filter some line

crontab - adds all the printed stuff into the crontab file.

you can use this, I hop it will help you.